# Tentative et tentation

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je n'arrive pas à faire la différence entre ces deux mots : *tentation* et *tentative*.

Lequel des deux signifie essai ?

Quelqu'un peut m'éclairer s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: C'est tentative qui signifie essai. On tente de faire quelque chose quand on essaye. On est tenté lorsqu'on parle de tentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux se rapportent également au verbe tenter.
Mais c'est la *tentative* qui signifie l'essai au sens que je m'imagine que tu mets à essai. (démarche en vue d'aboutir à / d'obtenir quelque chose).

Du temps de Rabelais, la *tentative* était le nom de... l'épreuve du baccalauréat en théologie.

Mais il est vrai que l'essai, au sens d'expérience n'est pas non plus totalement étranger à la *tentation*. Cet essai est néanmoins réservé à l'enfreinte d'une loi, d'une morale.

EDIT : Un truc pour distinguer les deux :

- Tu tentes un truc ? (usage transitif de tenter, voix active, tu fais l'action) => C'est une *tentative*.
- Tu es tenté de faire ? (voix passive, tu subis) => C'est de la *tentation*.

Answer (score 1):

— ***Tentative** : tenter une action*, l’agent est actif et essaye de réaliser quelque chose sans être  certain du résultat, cela correspond à "faire un essai" :

> Médaille d’or ? une *tentative* de record réussie !

— ***Tentation** : être tenté par une action*, l’agent est passif et ne s’est pas encore décidé de faire ou pas une *tentative*  :

> Je suis tenté par l’achat de cette voiture luxueuse, dois-je céder à la *tentation* ?

Dans le domaine de la morale :

> Le Diable tente le (futur) pécheur potentiel et lui propose de l’aider à réaliser une *tentative* (de faire un essai) pour obtenir ce qu’il désire le plus sans en avoir les moyens de le réaliser tout seul : des biens, du pouvoir une apparence flatteuse, l’amour…
>
> Il lui promet la réussite, en contre-partie le pécheur lui cédera en cas de réussite une partie ou la totalité de son âme ou de sa Vie … ce dernier est alors soumis à la *tentation* : être ou avoir, richesse immédiate ou épanouissement de soi à plus long terme …